# How to install the Hibernate plugin in Java NetBeans 14?

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, freemarker

I'm trying to install the Hibernate plugin in NetBeans version 14 with JDK 11 but when I try to do it this error is shown:

```
Some plugins require plugin Freemarker Integration to be installed.

The plugin Freemarker Integration is requested in implementation version 238.  

The following plugin is affected: Hibernate
```

I've tried to fix it editing the file MANIFEST which is on the file "org-netbeans-libs-freemarker" in the lines 11 and 16 writing the version 238 instead of the one that was there, which was another one.

I expect to be able to install Hibernate. Any solution?

This is a screen shot of the error that appears when I try to install it:

[image: Installer error]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the Hibernate plugin is no longer supported in NetBeans, and there is no solution to your problem. But here is some relevant information so you can understand why:

- The issue you are facing is already documented in the unresolved bug report [NETBEANS-4786
  unable to install Hibernate in Netbeans 12](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4786) from 2020:

> I unable to install Hibernate plugin . I already install freeMaker
> plugin.

- However, NetBeans does not currently provide a plugin for Hibernate, and it's use has not been officially supported for several years. Open bug [NETBEANS-2599
  Hibernate Plugin Addition](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2599) from 2019 documents this:

> Bringing back Hibernate plugin to the IDE, which was **removed due to
> licensing restrictions**

- I don't know whether that is related to the migration of NetBeans to Apache, but nothing has been done yet, and there is no reason to assume that there ever will be any progress.
- The workaround that you tried (*"...editing the file MANIFEST..."*) is comprehensively documented in the comments for [NETBEANS-4468
  No dependent plugins are available at Apache NetBeans plugin portal for Hibernate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468), but unfortunately it does not work for NetBeans releases 14 or later. (Like you, I have tried it.)

So your only options are:

- Use an *unsupported* version of NetBeans (i.e. prior to NetBeans 14) to install the *unsupported* Hibernate plugin using the *unsupported* workaround you mentioned. That is definitely not an approach I'd recommend.
- Get by without having the Hibernate plugin in NetBeans.